# Is it possible to build gcc 1.0 without a C compiler?

Tags: gcc, build

Is it possible to build `gcc 1.0` with only an assembler, without any C compilers? If it is possible, how can I build it? If it is not possible, how did the first C compiler come out?

Let's say if we have a new architecture of CPU with a new set of instructions, and the only software that has been made for it, is the assembler, then how can I build a `gcc` compiler for it?

Answer (score 1):

Early versions of GCC were written in C.  At the time, the operating systems GCC targeted came with at least a rudimentary C compiler (maybe for K&R C only, without support for prototypes).  There was no bootstrap from assembler code involved, even in the first release.  For those who did not or could not build GCC by themselves, the FSF provided pre-built binaries on tape, for a fee.

Support for new architectures (if they support self-hosting at all) was and still is implemented using [cross-compilers](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html#Building-a-cross-compiler).